# Error's when posting data to smartsheets columns via api (python)

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api

So I am currently attempting to post data through the smarthsheets api. My data is stored in a list of tuples such as this for an example:

[('hello','hi','description here'), ('I', 'Appreciate','the','help')] <- this is obviously for reference but just want to clarify that all the data in the tuples are strings. Now when I go to post the data that I have to smartsheets I get the following error,

```
{"response": {"statusCode": 404, "reason": "Not Found", "content": {"errorCode": 1006, "message": "Not Found", "refId": "ra7osyecdyx8"}}}
{"result": {"code": 1006, "errorCode": 1006, "message": "Not Found", "name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "refId": "ra7osyecdyx8", "shouldRetry": false, "statusCode": 404}}
```

The code that I have that I'm using to get the sheetid of the sheet in smartsheets and then add to the column is as

```
def getColumns(sheetId, columnList):
    try:
        columnList = []
        action = smart.Sheets.get_columns(
            sheetId, include_all=True)
        columns = action.data
        for col in columns:
            columnList.append(col.id)
        return columnList
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(30)
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print(e)

def addToColumns(columnId, sheetId, columnData):
    try:
        column_spec = smartsheet.models.Column({
            'title': columnData,
            'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER',
            'options': ["One"],
            'index': 0
            })
        
        response = smart.Sheets.update_column(
            columnId,
            sheetId,
            column_spec

        )
        print(response)
    except ValueError as e:
        # time.sleep(30)
        # print(traceback.format_exc())
        print(e)
    getColumns()

    return
```

These two functions are called in the main piece of code here:

```
try:

        response = requests.request(
            'GET', url, headers=headers, data=payload, params=params)
        data = response.json()
        cloudcheckrBillingData = []
        columnList = []
        sheetColumns = getColumns(cloudCheckrCurrentMonth, columnList)
        for x in data['BillByAccount']:
            # print(data['BillByAccount'])
            billData = x['Account'], x['MonthlyToDateBill'], x['MonthlyToDateCost'], x['MonthlyToDateCredits']
            cloudcheckrBillingData.append(billData)


        for r in sheetColumns:
            for i in cloudcheckrBillingData:
                for string in i:
                    addToColumns(r, cloudCheckrCurrentMonth, string)
                
        return 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The goal I am trying to reach is to take the data that I visualized above that is stored in the "cloudcheckrBillingData" list and then iterate over the column id's and the tuples to add the data appropriately in the addToColumns() function. The error happens in the addToColumns() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% following the scenario you've described -- but here's some feedback that may be helpful.

First, a `404` error in response to a Smartsheet API call most often means that (at least) one of the IDs that's specified in the URI either doesn't exist OR the user who issued the API call (i.e., the user account that owns the token that's being used to authenticate the API call) doesn't have access to the item. For example, if I use my API token to issue an [Update Column](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#update-column) request with URI `PUT /sheets/123/columns/456`, I'd receive a `404` response if any of the following are true:

- No sheet having ID `123` exists.
- Sheet having ID `123` exists, but it does not contain a column having ID `456`.
- Sheet having ID `123` exists, but I don't have adequate permissions to access it.

Let's step back from the `404` error for a minute though, as I think there may be a larger issue. Do I understand correctly that you're trying to add new **rows** of data to the sheet? If so, then you'd want to use the [Add Rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#add-rows) operation to do that. Your function `addToColumns` is calling the [Update Column](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#update-column) operation, which is intended to do things like update the properties of a column (data type, etc.), move a column, or rename a column. Based on the scenario you've described, that doesn't seem like the right operation.

Comment: I think you're exactly right , I was attempting to add to the column thinking it would take the column ID and add new cells but, I think what I really needed was to add rows. Thank you Kim!

Comment: Happy to help! If you run into issues with the **Add Rows** operation, please feel free to post a new question here on Stack Overflow.